# Php: Keep same filename when downloading from server

Tags: php

I'm downloading a file through php script and everything work perfectly except one ugly truth. The downloaded file keep the same url and with original name appended. How do I maintain the same filename when file downloaded?

```
http://bachday.com/index.php?page=custom&file=mmailer/download.php?mfile=sample.docx
```

```
if (isset($_GET['mfile'])) {
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/oc-content/plugins/mmailer/pfile/'.$_GET['mfile'];

    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && preg_match('/\.docx$/',$file)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/docx');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    readfile($file);
    /*
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo (readfile($file));*/


    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "Error 404: File Not Found: 
$file";
    }
```

Comment: try this code.  `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}.{$file_ending}");` the difference is in concatenating.

Answer (score 3):

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name_of_file_here"')` would have done the trick. You are passing the full path of the file there as `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");` since your $file contains full path. Instead just send the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));`

This line can perhaps solve the issue.

Comment: Please explain how can this code possibly solve the issue.

Comment: .basename($file) would return the last part(the file name along with the extension) from the $file string, which is the issue asked above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['mfile'])) {
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/oc-content/plugins/mmailer/pfile/'.$_GET['mfile'];

    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && preg_match('/\.docx$/',$file)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/docx');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");//use basename to extract filename from full file path
    readfile($file);
    /*
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo (readfile($file));*/


    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "Error 404: File Not Found: 
$file";
    }
```

Comment: `"...filename=\"basename($file)\""` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake... forgot to keep the function out of quotations..

now you can use the original filename in the server and send it to the downloaded file